# Using the result of the SQL "Messages" pane

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms

I have an existing SQL 2005 stored procedure that for some reason, outputs its results in the *Messages* pane in SSMS instead of the *Results* pane. (Its actually a CLR procedure already compiled and deployed to all our servers, and used for another daily process. So I can't change it, I just want to use its output.)

For the sake of discussion, here's a stored proc that behaves the same way:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[OutputTest] 
    @Param1  int, @Param2 varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    PRINT 'C,10000,15000';
    PRINT 'D,30000,90000';
    PRINT 'E,500,50000';
END
```

So no actual *SELECT* statement in there, and if you run this, you'll see these results only on the Messages pane.

Is there any way for me to **use** these results as part of a larger query? Put them in a temp table or something, so I can parse them out?

None of the "normal stuff" works, because there is no true "output" here:

```
INSERT INTO #output
EXEC OutputTest 100, 'bob'
```

just shows

```
C,10000,15000
D,30000,90000
E,500,50000

(0 row(s) affected)
```

on the messages pane, and the temp table doesn't actually get anything put into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot trap, catch or use these messages from within SQL Server.  You can, however, receive them from within a client application.

Answer (score 6):

Can you execute the stored proc from C# code? If so, you might be able to hook into the SqlCommand event called SqlInfoMessage:

```
SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection("server=.;
            database=Northwind;integrated Security=SSPI;");

_con.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(_con_InfoMessage);
```

The event handler will look like this:

```
static void _con_InfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
{
    string myMsg = e.Message;            
}
```

The "e.Message" is the message printed out to the message window in SQL Server Mgmt Studio.

While it won't be pretty and might require some ugly parsing code, at least you could get a hold of those messages that way, I hope!

Marc

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way but even if there is I think you should seriously consider whether it is a good idea. This sounds like a fudge which can only cause you pain in the long term. Creating an alternative proc that does exactly what you want sounds to me like a better plan.

Comment: Maybe true, but if it *is* possible, there are other applications of this technique, like parsing the result of "SET STATISTICS IO ON" that appears on the Messages Pane when you are tuning a query.

Comment: That's an interesting point but I imagine that parsing is being done by the client app and not the sql server. Would it not be possible to get hold of the CLR proc, fix the problem and release a second version to the server so that you don't affect the existing consumers of this proc?

Comment: I'll have to do that if this ultimately turns out not to be possible. Thought I might see first if I could use the existing proc, though.

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to get messages from the message pane in your result. 
if you think about it the SSMS is just a client that parses those messages the way you see it.

if you wan to use them in your app take a look at [Connection Events in ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0hee08w.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could think that this might be possible is if the output is printed via the RAISERROR command.  In that case, you might be able to capture it elsewhere using TRY/CATCH.

But that's just an idea: I've never done it.  In fact, the only thing we do that's remotely close is that we have a command line tool to run stored procedures in batch jobs rather than using sql server agent to schedule them.  This way all of our nightly jobs are scheduled in one place (the windows task scheduler) rather than two, and the command line tool captures the anything printed to the message window into a common logging system that we monitor.  So some of procedures will output quite a lot of detail to that window.

Comment: That's similar to how the existing process works. We have an external script that runs this proc on each server, and captures the message output in a text file, then goes through and utilizes that text file. 

But if I'm gonna have to use shell scripts anyway, I'd probably just gather the information directly rather than calling the proc (the existing proc reports some drive space statistics that T-SQL can't call directly)